# Inverse of Python's unicodedata.name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, utf-8

There is the built-in method unicodedata.name which given a unicode character will return a human readable name, e.g.:

```
unicodedata.name(chr(0x2704)) == "WHITE SCISSORS"
```

Is there anything out there that will provide the inverse? I'm looking for something like:

```
unicodedata.name("WHITE SCISSORS") == chr(0x2704) or 0x2704
```

I could easily loop over all the possible values, build up a map, but that seems like it could be inefficient and was hoping something like this already exists. I am using Python 3 so am open to 3-only solutions.

Comment: In case anyone is curious, it's for this google hangouts to IRC bridge I forked and am improving. I wanted this so it would translate emojis between hangouts and irc into text like :bear-face: instead of 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`unicodedata.lookup`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.lookup):

```
In [5]: unicodedata.lookup("WHITE SCISSORS")
Out[5]: '✄'
```

This returns a character, use `ord` to get integer ordinal:

```
In [7]: ord(unicodedata.lookup("WHITE SCISSORS"))
Out[7]: 9988 # hex(9988) is 0x2704
```